# Pcrecpp destructor

Tags: regex, string, pcre

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::string s1;
   pcrecpp::RE re("(.*)");
   re.PartialMatch("This is a test progream", &s1);

   return 0;
}
```

I want to store the match result to `s1`, but when I am running the program, an error occurs:

[image: Screen-shot of VS error message and code location]

This is the stack trace information:

[image: stack trace]

pcrecpp version: *8.36*
compiler: *vs2005*

Comment: Can you show a stack trace where the breakpoint occurred? If you step up to the calling method or function, can you determine what pointer is being freed by LocalPcreFree?

That said, my first guess is that this is an internal pcre bug due to the malloc-free definitions changing between when malloc is called on the first pcre-internal global, and when free is called on it. In other words, when malloc was called, it was using a different heap to when free was called. Perhaps changing the order of includes will help.

Comment: Thank you. I will change the order of includes and try again. The  stack trace i attached below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a better way to solve this problem. As pcrecpp.dll will malloc memory, and this will cause faults on windows. So, first, I build the pcre.dll; then add pcrecpp files to my project, thus solve the memory malloc problem.
    Use pcre.8.36 as an example:
    1. Use pcre files to generate pcre.dll:

```
pcre_byte_order.c
pcre_chartables.c
pcre_compile.c
pcre_config.c
pcre_dfa_exec.c
pcre_exec.c
pcre_fullinfo.c
pcre_get.c
pcre_globals.c
pcre_jit_compile.c
pcre_maketables.c
pcre_newline.c
pcre_ord2utf8.c
pcre_refcount.c
pcre_string_utils.c
pcre_study.c
pcre_tables.c
pcre_ucd.c
pcre_valid_utf8.c
pcre_version.c
pcre_xclass.c

pcre.h
pcre_internal.h
ucp.h
config.h
```

2. Add

   `pcre_scanner.cpp
   pcre_stringpiece.cpp
   pcrecpp.cpp
   pcre_scanner.h
   pcre_stringpiece.h
   pcrecpparg.h`
   to my project, OK!